# записать значение в таблицу

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, dapper

есть метод с помошью которого хочу записать информацию в базе с List, когда вызываю метод он сохраняет первое значение с List и когда Foreach доходит до второго значения await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(); выдает ошибку

**'ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'INSERT_PROBLEM_LOAN_TEMPORARY'**

**как записать всю информацию с List в Table?**

```
public async Task Insert(List<Details> problem)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(con))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LBINFO.PROBLEM_LOANS_MANAGEMENT.INSERT_PROBLEM_LOAN_TEMPORARY", conn))
        {
            await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
            foreach (var item in problem)
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MODULE", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.MODULE;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("P_HR_CODE", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.HrCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("P_LOAN_ID", OracleDbType.Number).Value = Int32.Parse(item.LoanId);

                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_PROBLEM_LOAN_TEMPORARY(P_MODULE VARCHAR2, P_HR_CODE VARCHAR2, P_LOAN_ID NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO LBINFO.PROBLEM_LOANS_TEMPORARY(MODULE, HR_CODE, LOAN_ID)
           VALUES(P_MODULE, P_HR_CODE, P_LOAN_ID);
    COMMIT;
  END;
```

Comment: А прямой INSERT рвботает? Типы аргументов точно правильно указаны? Вместо `AddWithValue` попробуйте `Add` и явным заданием типа параметра. https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: @aepot Да работает, с List он делает INSERT первого значения, но когда Foreach доходит до второго значения потом просиходит ошибка

Comment: А, вынесите `await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();` из цикла!

Comment: @aepot вынес await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync(),поменял на Add , Но все равно таже ошибка

Comment: Покажите обновленный код. Отредактируйте пост.

Comment: @aepot обновил пост

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MODULE", OracleType.VarChar).Value = item.MODULE;` - вот так указывается тип, сделайте остальные в том же духе https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracletype?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @aepot таже ошибка

Comment: Все, я понял. Сейчас дам ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете команду 1 раз, добавляете в нее 3 параметра, выполняете. Все ок, далее на второй итерации цикла вы добавляете в нее еще 3 параметра и их становится 6. Получаете соответствующую ошибку.

```
await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync();
foreach (var item in problem)
{
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("LBINFO.PROBLEM_LOANS_MANAGEMENT.INSERT_PROBLEM_LOAN_TEMPORARY", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MODULE", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.MODULE;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_HR_CODE", OracleDbType.VarChar).Value = item.HrCode;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("P_LOAN_ID", OracleDbType.Number).Value = int.Parse(item.LoanId);

        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    }
}
```